# Python File System Reader Performance

Tags: python, performance, filesystems

I need to scan a file system for a list of files, and log those who don't exist. Currently I have an input file with a list of the 13 million files which need to be investigated. This script needs to be run from a remote location, as I do not have access/cannot run scripts directly on the storage server.

My current approach works, but is relatively slow. I'm still fairly new to Python, so I'm looking for tips on speeding things up.

```
import sys,os
from pz import padZero #prepends 0's to string until desired length
output = open('./out.txt', 'w')
input = open('./in.txt', 'r')
rootPath = '\\\\server\share\' #UNC path to storage
for ifid in input:
    ifid = padZero(str(ifid)[:-1], 8) #extracts/formats fileName
    dir = padZero(str(ifid)[:-3], 5) #exracts/formats the directory containing the file
    fPath = rootPath + '\\' + dir + '\\' + ifid + '.tif'
    try:
        size = os.path.getsize(fPath) #don't actually need size, better approach?
    except:
        output.write(ifid+'\n')
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is basically always going to be slow, because you're making 13 million queries to the server. If there aren't too many files on the server, it would almost certainly be quicker just to get the entire directory listing down and then do all the processing locally. Can you do that?

Comment: BTW [`os.path.exists`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists).

Comment: There are 71k+ directories of about 1000 files each. I'm going to try your solution and see how it goes.

Comment: As a sidenote, **any** time you are using backslash literals in a string, use a raw string `r'\\server\share'` instead of the plain string `'\\\\server\share'`. As it stands you're lucky that `\s` has no special meaning, but if you'd tried to write the path `'\\server\new_files'` you would have a newline where you don't want one.

Comment: @Li-aungYip Thats not a real path, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dirs = collections.defaultdict(set)

for file_path in input:
    file_path = file_path.rjust(8, "0")
    dir, name = file_path[:-3], file_path

    dirs[dir].add(name)

for dir, files in dirs.iteritems():
    for missing_file in files - set(glob.glob("*.tif")):
        print missing_file
```

### Explanation

First read the input file into a dictionary of directory: filename. Then for each directory, list all the TIFF files in that directory on the server, and (set) subtract this from the collection of filenames you should have. Print anything that's left.

<sub>EDIT: Fixed silly things. Too late at night when I wrote this!</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I had to expand on this a little but it's working well. Hopefully by tomorrow I'll know if it's actually any faster.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to be I/O bound, especially on a network, so any changes you can make to your script will result in very minimal speedups, but off the top of my head:

```
import os

input, output = open("in.txt"), open("out.txt", "w")

root = r'\\server\share'

for fid in input:
    fid  = fid.strip().rjust(8, "0")
    dir  = fid[:-3]      # no need to re-pad
    path = os.path.join(root, dir, fid + ".tif")
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        output.write(fid + "\n")
```

I don't really expect that to be any faster, but it is arguably easier to read.

Other approaches may be faster. For example, if you expect to touch most of the files, you could just pull a complete recursive directory listing from the server, convert it to a Python `set()`, and check for membership in that rather than hitting the server for many small requests. I will leave the code as an exercise...

Answer (score 0):

That padZero and string concatenation stuff looks to me like it would take a good percent of time.

What you want it to do is spend all its time reading the directory, very little else.

Do you have to do it in python? I've done similar stuff in C and C++. Java should be pretty good too.

Comment: Why not Python? It's not like it's going to magically speed up if you use C -- the issue is still the 13 million server queries. I highly doubt the string processing stuff takes a significant amount of time compared to that.

Comment: @katrielalex: The string processing stuff *shouldn't* be big compared to the I/O, but you can't rely on that. Too many times I've seen it. A few random stackshots would tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a shell command to get the full listing of files in all directories and subdirectories in one hit. Hopefully this will minimise the amount of requests you need to make to the server.

You can get a listing of the remote server's files by doing something like:

- Linux: `mount` the shared drive as `/shared/directory/` and then do `ls -R /shared/directory > ~/remote_file_list.txt`
- Windows: Use `Map Network Drive` to mount the shared drive as drive letter `X:`, then do `dir /S X:/shared_directory > C:/remote_file_list.txt`

Use the same methods to create a listing of your local folder's contents as `local_file_list.txt`. You python script will then reduce to an exercise in text processing.

Note: I did actually have to do this at work.